# Should information from an other site be blockquoted?

Tags: discussion, blockquote

[Difference between Bubbling and Tunneling events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736444/difference-between-bubbling-and-tunneling-events/16736533#16736533) This answer here is being blockquoted now. The information comes from the first link and is pretty much the same. Should it be blockquoted?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, since this is a quote, you should indeed use markup to indicate that it came from that source and is not original.